# GetParameters error when deploying react code in AWS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to deploy I react app in AWS Elastic and I added some parameters. However, when trying to build via pipeline and codeBuild, I'm getting the error below:

`Phase context status code: Decrypted Variables Error Message: AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::MYCODE:assumed-role/codebuild-QA-service-role/AWSCodeBuild-4701b85f-fc5b-49c8-b2f9-f634930aca4f is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameters on resource: arn:aws:ssm:sa-east-1:MYCODE:parameter/PARAMETERVALUE because no identity-based policy allows the ssm:GetParameters action`

I tried using the syntax below to the user `codebuild-QA-service-role` to allow it, however still getting that error

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DescribeParameters"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameters"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:sa-east-1:CODEHERE:parameter/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are the parameters String or SecureString? Because if they are SecureString you need to add decrypt permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If your paramereters are of type SecureString, you need permissions to decrypt them. Check the docs for the policy needed:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ssm:GetParameter*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:sa-east-1:CODEHERE:parameter/*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "kms:Decrypt"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:sa-east-1:CODEHERE:key/YOURKEY"
    }
]
```

}

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-parameter-store.html#parameter-store-policies

Comment: Those are not SecureString, but I added your code as well and got same error. 
At same time, I ask my self if I really need to send those parameters, because all of them are related to AWS stuff.